# How often are the 5 community cards the best hand?

Tags: nlhe, odds, probability

Can we calculate the probability that the 5 community cards are the best hand, i.e., that all remaining players chop the pot? I imagine that this probability drops as the number of players increases.

Comment: assuming all players play through to the finish or just playing normally? some of those pots probably ends before the showdown with polarizing bluffs.

Comment: @Unihedron  For starters assume all players remain.

Comment: How many players are playing? For starters.

Comment: @user70889  Last night 4 players stayed to the river and the pot was split four ways because no player could beat AAKKT